# JS ES6 class constructor behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-class

I have a question regarding the constructor in ES6 classes.

I have defined the following class Game:

```
module.exports = class Game {constructor() {}};
```

Now I create an instance like that. With and without params:

```
let Game = require('./lib/models/game'); console.log(new Game());console.log(new Game(1,2,3));
```

If I create an instance with params, I get no error or exception.
What's the reason for that?

Comment: In javascript class is also function and you can pass as many param as you want in javascript function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because JavaScript functions don't check that the number of arguments you provide when calling them is the same as the number of formal parameters. This isn't just true of constructor functions, it's true of all functions. *(Unless, of course, explicit code is added to the function to do the check.)*

If you provide more arguments than there are formal parameters, you can access those via the special `arguments` pseudo-array (but keep reading):

```js
function foo() {
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i ) {
        console.log(`arguments[${i}] =`, arguments[i]);
    }
}
foo("a", "b");
```

Output:

```
arguments[0] = a
arguments[1] = b
```

Similarly, if you declare formal parameters and values for them aren't given, their values will be `undefined.`

```js
function foo(arg) {
    console.log("arg:", arg);
}
foo();
```

Output:

```
arg: undefined
```

`arguments` used to be used for variable argument lists quite a lot; but as of ES2015, the shift is toward using a rest parameter instead:

```js
function foo(a, ...rest) {
    console.log("a = ", a);
    for (let i = 0; i < rest.length; ++i ) {
        console.log(`rest[${i}] =`, rest[i]);
    }
}
foo("a", "b", "c");
```

Output:

```
a = a
rest[0] = b
rest[1] = c
```